# WPF tetbox databinding options

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, textbox

```
<TextBox Name="txtSearch" Margin="0,0,0,0"  Height="20" Width="215"  AcceptsReturn="True"              TextChanged="txtSearch_TextChanged" ></TextBox>
```

what's the difference between doing binding `Path` and Binding `ElementName` :

```
<TextBox Name="txtFind" Text="{Binding Path=txtSearch}"></TextBox>
```

and

```
<TextBox Name="txtFind" Text="{Binding ElementName=txtSearch}"></TextBox>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One references the name of an object, the other references the property of that object.  What you should have is something like :

```
<TextBox Name="txtFind" Text="{Binding ElementName=txtSearch, Path=Text}"></TextBox>
```

Which makes more sense.

Comment: thx that worked fine :) so for more information what does the path property exactly indicates ? and is it mandatory for this kind of databinding ?

Comment: I wouldn't say it's mandatory.  You could be binding the textbox to a string rather than a business object or another XAML control (like you have here), so the path would be obvious and unnecessary.  Plus, the object you are using could have an overridden 'tostring' property, and the textbox would probably use that.  Just good practice to use it normally though.